# Game development for Windows Phone after XNA

Tags: windows-phone

Is there any replacement for XNA to develop games on windows phone? I know that Microsoft will end it's support for this technology in 2014, but what next? Silverlight is not suitable for 3d games I guess, so Direct X?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MonoGame](http://monogame.codeplex.com/) could be an option maybe?